Universal Connection Pool already exists error (Oracle UCP) SpringBoot Custom DataSource
I am facing below issue when running on cloud after few DB calls are done, unfortunately not able to reproduce locally. Need advice or direction if something is missing -
Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Universal Connection Pool already exists in the Universal Connection Pool Manager. Universal Connection Pool cannot be added to the Universal Connection Pool Manager
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:378)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:68)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:91)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:149)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.createUniversalConnectionPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:985)
    ... 37 common frames omitted

I have following DataSource bean - It was migrated from OracleDataSource (dataSource.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true) - this is deprecated)
@Bean("testDataSource")
    DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
        logger.info("Setting UP DataSource for : {}", DB_POOL_PROVIDER_UCP);
        
        PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pds.setURL(url);
        pds.setUser(username);
        pds.setPassword(password);
        
        pds.setConnectionPoolName("TestDBPool");
        
        pds.setMinPoolSize(2);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(3);
        
        pds.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(60);
        pds.setMaxStatements(100);
        pds.setAbandonedConnectionTimeout(60);
        pds.setConnectionWaitTimeout(30);
        pds.setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(240);
        pds.setTimeoutCheckInterval(60);
        
        pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(false); //Just one node
        pds.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
        pds.setSQLForValidateConnection("select 1 from dual");
        
        return pds;
    }

And most places DataSource is being used for

org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure

And -

try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection())

SpringBootVersion - 3.3.0
UCP - 21.9.0.0
ojdbc11 - 21.9.0.0
I have tried to get ConnectionPoolName after starting application locally hitting random API but it just Printing the Above DB Pool Name -
    String[] poolNames = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager().getConnectionPoolNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < poolNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(poolNames[i]);
    }

POM Snippet -
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
        </dependency>


add:
  <argLine>-Doracle.ucp.destroyOnReload=true</argLine>

to your pom, or try use this flag on terminal. This work for me

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The "Universal Connection Pool already exists" error is thrown only when you try to create two connection pools with same name. I see that you are initializing your datasource in getDataSource() method, so you need to make sure that it is being called only once. If this method is called more than once then you will run into same issue as shown in error.

This is an @Bean method which will be proxied and it will return the same instance after it has been called once.

Then there could be some other application running in same jvm which is creating a pool with same name.

@SaurabhVerma it is single app container.

Could you try setting below jvm system property and see if that helps.
-Doracle.ucp.destroyOnReload=true
The error  occurs only when you try to create a pool with an existing pool name.
